# How am I misunderstanding Django's get_or_create function?

Tags: python, django

We have a Django project that has a bunch of experiments, and each experiment can have zero or more text tags. The tags are stored in a table, and there is a many-to-many relationship between experiments and tags:

```python
class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=32, null=False, validators=[validate_unicode_slug], db_index=True, unique=True)

class Experiment(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

If I add a tag to an experiment with `get_or_create()` it does the right thing, filling in the tag table and the joining table. If I remove the tag from the experiment with `remove()` it also does the right thing by removing just the row from the joining table and leaving the tag table intact. But if I later come to re-add the tag to the experiment, it throws a uniqueness constraint error because it's trying to re-add the tag to the tag table. E.g:

```python
    tag, created = experiment.tags.get_or_create(text="B")
    experiment.tags.remove(*experiment.tags.filter(text="B"))
    tag, created = experiment.tags.get_or_create(text="B")  # It fails the uniqueness test here.
```

Removing the uniqueness constraint just means it adds a new tag with identical text.

So is it possible to add and remove tags arbitrarily by just modifying the joining table if a tag already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate this process, because it's not that simple with relations.

```
tag, created = experiment.tags.get_or_create(text="B")
experiment.tags.remove(*experiment.tags.filter(text="B"))
tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(text="B")
experiment.tags.add(tag)
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that one. Thanks @NixonSparrow